# create-react-app import internal script getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Im new to react, and I've cloned "create-react-app" from https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started to be my first react project. Currently I have a problem which is when I'm importing internal jQuery js within html, it gives me a console error like this :

> the error is : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

My "body" html codes :

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="src/assets/scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

As you can see from the code I imported jquery-3.4.1.min.js before closing body tag. It has no problem when use from external link ex:"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" but it has an error when i import from internal folder.

Why does this happen? I searched the problem from several sources and it didn't give me any solution. can anyone help please

Comment: So how does your `myscript.js` looks like? Please add the code.

Comment: it's just a console log like console.log("text");

Comment: It's appear to be the same whether i import myscript or jquery script or another js it would give the same error

Comment: The error very often occurs when the script path is incorrect, and the browser is attempting load a 404 error page, which begins with '<html>'.
If you need to include jquery locally - ie not from CDN, then put it in the public folder and reference like <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json"></script>

Comment: Edited, I change it to import JQuery file from internal folder to make it clear

Comment: @Andrew yeah I thought so, but do you know where I get the right path with create-react-app i  use ?

Comment: @Andrew so do you mean I must change all of my folder (including js/css/images/) directory into directory inside public folder? So it can't be use outside of public folder i.e:"src/assets/jquery.js"?

Comment: @Billy I guess I'm saying create-react-app generally expects things in your app to be part of the React application, imported somewhere by your app code, then bundled up with Webpack. CRA - and the dev server especially -  doesn't really understand just referencing a js file in that way.
If you do have a standalone script like jquery, then yes, put it in the public folder (or referencing from the CDN is good) If it's part of your app, import it in your app code and let webpack handle it.

Comment: @Andrew Oh I see, I think I'll just have to change the directory like you said, Thank you Andrew But can we change %PUBLIC_URL% into root of project folder?

Comment: that one I don't know - sorry.